# How to load a JAR stored inside your application resources in a URLClassLoader

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

I'm trying to load a JAR file in a `URLClassLoader`. This JAR file is stored in the resources of my project, and its working fine with the following code when I'm running my project using maven:

```
new URLClassLoader(
    new URL[]{MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("dependencies/dependency.jar")},
    ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent()
);
```

However, when I build the project using `mvn clean install` and I then try to run the generate JAR using `java -jar myapp.jar` it seems like the `dependency.jar` is not loaded. The `dependency.jar` file is properly stored inside the project JAR under `dependencies/dependency.jar`, but it's not read.

I assume that it cannot be loaded from inside a JAR file, but is their a workaround?

I think a solution would be to use `getResourceAsStream`, but I would then need to transform this stream into a URL.

If possible I'd like to use a solution that wouldn't involve a temporary file created to store the content of `dependency.jar`.

Comment: dependency.jar is located into your jar file? if so where exactly?

Comment: Yes, it's in the resources from my project, so in the built JAR it's located in `dependencies/dependency.jar`

Comment: have your tried MyClass.class.getResource("/dependencies/dependency.jar") instead?

Comment: Well then it's not even working with maven ^^'

Comment: yes but with java -jar myapp.jar

Comment: please also note that I removed .getClassLoader()

Comment: try to use Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() as parent CL

Comment: With `MyClass.class.getResource("/dependencies/dependency.jar")` I get the same error as before (ClassNotFound). I can't change the parent CL, I have to use the current one :/

Comment: Have you checked if MyClass.class.getResource("/dependencies/dependency.jar") returns a non null value?

Comment: It is indeed not null, if I `toString()` it I get the absolute path to the resource, with a `!` after the JAR name to show that it's a zip file.

Comment: What about what you use in your question "MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("dependencies/dependency.jar")" is it null ?

Comment: No, it isn't either. As I said I feel like the issue is that the URLClassLoader cannot load a JAR from within another JAR :/

Comment: Interesting, It means that it cannot read a zip in a zip

Comment: which version of Java do you use?

Comment: If you get the absolute path with a ! maybe you could use JarURLConnection http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your problem is due to the fact that **it cannot read a zip in zip**, so you should copy your jar file into a temporary file and provide this temporary file to your `URLClassLoader` as next:

```
// Get the URL of my jar file
URL url = MyClass.class.getResource("/dependencies/dependency.jar");
// Create my temporary file
Path path = Files.createTempFile("dependency", "jar");
// Delete the file on exit
path.toFile().deleteOnExit();
// Copy the content of my jar into the temporary file
try (InputStream is = url.openStream()) {
    Files.copy(is, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
// Create my CL with this new URL
URLClassLoader myCL = new URLClassLoader(
    new URL[]{path.toUri().toURL()}, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent()
);
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid that's what I'll have to do, thanks. I just wanted to find out if there was another solution.

Comment: I'm not sure that  StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING is needed since Files.createTempFile is not supposed to create twice the same file.  Do you face issues if you don't add it?

Comment: Well, `Files.copy` tries to create the file. It's even written in the documentation : "By default, the copy fails if the target file already exists or is a symbolic link."